# numerically solving

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I am trying to solve for [Lambda] as a function of a (unknown) from this expression

```
202.[2.51521 + 1/(-1 + E^(202. λ))] + 
 802.[2.52457 + 1/(-1 + E^(802. λ))] + 
 1802.[2.52632 + 1/(-1 + E^(1802. λ))] + 
 3202.[2.52694 + 1/(-1 + E^(3202. λ))] + 
 5002.[2.52722 + 1/(-1 + E^(5002. λ))]=a
```

I tried with Reduce and FindRoot, and as neither of them helped I think closed form expression can not be obtained. Any suggestion how to get numerical solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `FindRoot` to solve once given specific values for `a`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Only after those square brackets are replaced by parenthesis

Comment: Anyway, the function is too steep and you'll probably need a few tricks

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks. But I want to express λ as a function of a. Sorry about the square brackets.

Comment: What's the problem with making a function that takes $\lambda$ as an argument and calls `FindRoot`?

Comment: [I have nothing against square brackets.]

Comment: `... /. h_[e_] /; NumericQ[h] :> h e` -- who needs parentheses, anyway?  A sticky = key can be really annoying, though, but there's a cure for that, too: `ReleaseHold[Hold[ ...] /. Set -> Equal]`.

Answer (score 3):

In such cases I prefer to get an idea from numerical solution.

```
f[x_] = 202. (2.51521 + 1/(-1 + E^(202. x))) + 802. (2.52457 + 1/(-1 + E^(802. x))) + 1802. (2.52632 + 1/(-1 + E^(1802. x))) + 3202. (2.52694 + 1/(-1 + E^(3202. x))) + 5002. (2.52722 + 1/(-1 + E^(5002. x)));
data = Table[{a, x /. FindRoot[f[x] == a, {x, -0.001}]}, {a, -100, 100, 10}];
ListPlot[data]
Fit[data, {1, a, a^2}, a]
```

[image]

> $-0.000231828 - 1.11206 \times 10^{-8} a - 5.50983 \times 10^{-13} a^2$

So we have three steps here. First I solve it for different `a`, then store them in `data`. And then I go for a polynomial fit. As you can see within the defined range of `a [-100,100]` it is almost linear. You can check with different `a` values. For higher `a` you have to take more terms in your polynomial.